# Drilldown navigation in Android tabhost

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

I have an android tabhost with a listview inside, when I click on a listviewitem I want to show a new list at the place of the old list inside the tablayout.
How can I implement this? (I need to use listviews not fragments)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: why -1? please comment..

Comment: One simple reason could be for the one stated in the tooltip of the downvote button: This question does not show any research effort - i.e., you don't show us what you've tried yourself which is something generally (and perhaps a little too strictly at times) expected here. As you probably know. =)

Comment: maybe the use of the English language for me is contradictory, with "How can I Implement this?" I mean: what (framework component) I lean on to succeed in this? the answer I found is activitygroup..

Comment: In that case, you should be as clear as you can and explain that. The more concise and relevant information you can provide, the less likely someone's going to do a drive-by downvoting for thinking your question looks lax. And kudos to you for finding your own solution. =)

Comment: the important thing is to understand it, vote -1 without comment the reason: this is lax ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I put an activitygroup inside the tabhost, like so:

```
public class DrillDownWrapper extends ActivityGroup {
    private ArrayList<View> history;
    public static DrillDownWrapper group;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        history = new ArrayList<View>();
        group = this;

        //put the first listactivity
        Intent i = new Intent(DrillDownWrapper.this, ListActivity.class);
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ListActivity", i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
        replaceView(view);
    }

    public void replaceView(View v) {
        history.add(v);
        setContentView(v);
    }

    public void back() {
        if(history.size() > 1) {
            history.remove(history.size()-1);
            setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrillDownWrapper.group.back();
        return;
    }
}
```

inside the listactivity you can get the context (ie to show a dialog) by calling getParent() method